# Sorting Observable Collection within ICollectionView with Gong Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently trying to create a WPF/C#/EF6 application that will emulate a Kanban board to track tasks with a target completion date. I am using the Gong-WPF-Drag-Drop nuget package to allow for nice dragging and dropping between swimlanes.

The core of the program focuses around 2 models, Swimlanes and Jobs (relevant parts of the classes below). I used the database first approach to generate these models. The Jobs collection is populated by an Observable Collection when retrieving Swimlane information via a helper method.

**SwimLanes**

```
public partial class Swimlane : BaseModel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Swimlane()
        {
            this.Jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
        }

        private int _slId;
        public int SlId 
        { 
            get { return _slId; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _slId, value); } 
        }

        private int _clientId;
        public int ClientId 
        { 
            get { return _clientId; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _clientId, value); } 
        }

        private string _slName;
        public string SlName 
        { 
            get { return _slName; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _slName, value); } 
        }

        private int _sortOrder;
        public int SortOrder 
        { 
            get { return _sortOrder; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _sortOrder, value); } 
        }


        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

**Jobs**

```
 public partial class Job : BaseModel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Job()
        {
        }

        private int _jobId;
        public int JobId 
        { 
            get { return _jobId; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _jobId, value); } 
        }

        private int _clientId;
        public int ClientId 
        { 
            get { return _clientId; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _clientId, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<int> _assignedSwimLane;
        public Nullable<int> AssignedSwimLane 
        { 
            get { return _assignedSwimLane; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _assignedSwimLane, value); } 
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name 
        { 
            get { return _name; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); } 
        }

        private string _owner_Fn;
        public string Owner_Fn 
        { 
            get { return _owner_Fn; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _owner_Fn, value); } 
        }

        private string _owner_Ln;
        public string Owner_Ln 
        { 
            get { return _owner_Ln; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _owner_Ln, value); } 
        }

        private string _owner_Email;
        public string Owner_Email 
        { 
            get { return _owner_Email; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _owner_Email, value); } 
        }

        private string _owner_Phone;
        public string Owner_Phone 
        { 
            get { return _owner_Phone; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _owner_Phone, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<System.DateTime> _scheduledIn;
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ScheduledIn 
        { 
            get { return _scheduledIn; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _scheduledIn, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<System.DateTime> _actualIn;
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualIn 
        { 
            get { return _actualIn; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _actualIn, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<System.DateTime> _scheduledCompletion;
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ScheduledCompletion 
        { 
            get { return _scheduledCompletion; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _scheduledCompletion, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<System.DateTime> _actualCompletion;
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualCompletion 
        { 
            get { return _actualCompletion; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _actualCompletion, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<System.DateTime> _scheduledDelivery;
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ScheduledDelivery 
        { 
            get { return _scheduledDelivery; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _scheduledDelivery, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<System.DateTime> _actualDelivery;
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualDelivery 
        { 
            get { return _actualDelivery; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _actualDelivery, value); } 
        }

        private Nullable<int> _sortOrder;
        public Nullable<int> SortOrder 
        { 
            get { return _sortOrder; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _sortOrder, value); } 
        }


    }
```

The application will sort the swimlanes by their order number using an ICollectionView which is created in the view model. The part that I am unable to achieve without breaking drag and drop functionality is applying a sort order/filter to the jobs within each lane.

**View model retrieval of swimlanes and creation of iCollectionView**

```
        private ObservableCollection<Swimlane> _boardColumns;
        public ObservableCollection<Swimlane> BoardColumns
        {
            get { return _boardColumns; }
            set { _boardColumns = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("BoardColumns"); }
        }

        private ICollectionView _swimlaneCollection;
        public ICollectionView SwimlaneCollection
        {
            get { return _swimlaneCollection; }
            set { _swimlaneCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SwimlaneCollection"); }
        }

        private async void InitializeVmAsync()
        {
            BoardColumns = await Utils.SwimlaneHelper.GetAllSwimlanes();
            SignalrDelegator = new Utils.Signalr.SignalrHubDelegator(this);
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization("BoardColumns", _boardColumnsLock);

            SwimlaneCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(BoardColumns);
            SwimlaneCollection.Filter = ViewFilter;
            SwimlaneCollection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SortOrder", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }
```

I have used the XAML approach to create a ICollectionView for the set of jobs for each swimlane and apply a default sort to it. However, this breaks drag and drop functionality with the gong package. It will no longer let me drag and drop across swimlanes.

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SwimlaneCollection}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <materialDesign:ColorZone Grid.Row="0" Mode="PrimaryDark"   Padding="16"  CornerRadius="4" 
                                                       materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"  Margin="8">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SlName}" 
                                               Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Jobs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource HoursCountConverter}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Jobs.Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}({0}) }"
                                               Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </materialDesign:ColorZone>

                                <ListView  VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                                            dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                                            dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}"
                                            dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultEffectDataTemplate="True"
                                            dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True">
                                    <ListView.Resources>
                                        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="JobsCvs" Source="{Binding Jobs}">
                                            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                                                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SortOrder" Direction="Ascending"/>
                                            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                                        </CollectionViewSource>
                                    </ListView.Resources>
                                    <ListView.ItemsSource>
                                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource JobsCvs}"/>
                                    </ListView.ItemsSource>
                                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>  
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                                        <DataTemplate >
                                            <views:Card/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <ListView.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Width="190">
                                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="-5" />
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ListView.Template>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                </ItemsControl>
```

How can I alter my approach to keep the sorting and filtering options of an ICollectionView, but still enable drag and drop between and within swimlanes? I haven't been able to find much information that shows manipulating a set within a set with ICollectionViews.

Comment: You should probably start by replacing the `HashSet<Job> Jobs` with an `ObservableCollection<Job>`, since you plan to change the collections (remove Job from one lane and add it to another). Then have a look at `CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties` to enable sorting of dynamically moved elements

Comment: However, I'm not familiar with your Drag-Drop framework and it's not completely clear to me, what exactly happens with your code thats different from expectation.

Comment: Actually, forget about `LiveSortingProperties`, it's something different :)

Comment: @grek40, These are generated models by EF6. I used the database first approach. In the helper method GetAllSwimLanes(), I replace all sets of jobs with an observable collection instead of an ICollection. Apologies for not making that clear. I'll edit my original post. The unexpected behavior is that when I try to drag and drop cards between lanes when using the ICollectionView for jobs is that I am unable to drop the card on any other lane. I simply receive the circle with a line through it as my cursor. I presume this is because the framework detects they are not the same type of parent.

Comment: There is another suspicious line: `dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}"` are you sure that your datacontext from some `DockPanel` that's not even part of your code is an appropriate drophandler?

Comment: The drop handler is in the parent VM, and it handles the inserting/updating of the records in the database through API call to update the database of the newly updated job. E.g., if it moves from lane 1 => 2. I have tried with this line commented, i.e. using the default drop handler and i receive the same behavior.

Comment: Confirmed the drop issue in case of using an explicit CollectionViewSource. Try setting up the filter and sorting via `var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Jobs);             view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SortOrder", ListSortDirection.Ascending));` etc. Bind directly to `Jobs` instead of creating an explicit `CollectionViewSource`. It should at least somehow work - though it doesn't answer how to do it right with gong drag drop.

Comment: Basically, a CollectionViewSource acts fine as a drag source, but not as a drop target.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by not implementing the sort (as I wanted internal drag'n'drop) and placing a handler on the views CollectionChanged event. This enabled me to set properties on the items in the collection.